# show serial port by friendly name not working probably on win 8.1 x64 and it is working on win 7 x32 using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, serial-port, windows-8.1

When I try to show my serial ports on Win 7 x32 by friendly name whether it is physical or virtual it works, but when I try it on Win 8.1 x64 only the virtual port shows.  When I remove the virtual it doesn`t show me any error in fact it just loads the form.

```
Try
     'Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\cimv2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort where Description='Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port'")
      Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\cimv2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort ")
      For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
          RichTextBox1.Text &= queryObj("Name") & Chr(32) & queryObj("DeviceID") & vbCr
      Next

Catch err As ManagementException
      MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " & err.Message)
End Try
```

Almost forgot I am trying to detect USB to RS-232 but no luck.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034688/wmi-not-working-after-upgrading-to-windows-10).  It's about Windows 10, but might be useful.

Comment: i tried something like that but i am looking for something that make the code look nice i will try again and thanks for the advice