# How to Change DNS with C# on Windows 10

Tags: c#, dns

I'm trying to change the DNS on Windows 10 through VB.NET.

I have code that works on Windows 7, however it does not work on Windows 10.

Here is my code for Windows 7 that changes the DNS:

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
    if ((bool)mo["IPEnabled"])
    {
        ManagementBaseObject objdns = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
        if (objdns != null)
        {
            string[] s = { "192.168.XX.X", "XXX.XX.X.XX" };
            objdns["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = s;
            mo.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", objdns, null);
```

My question is, how do I get this to work on Windows 10 OS?

Comment: Does this work on non-Windows 10 versions? What error do you get on Windows 10?

Comment: I don't get any errors on Windows 10, it just doesn't change the DNS.  But yes this code works for Windows 7 without any issues.

Comment: Hi Did you try to checkout this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, why do you want to change the DNS?

Answer (score 11):

First you need to get the NetworkInterface you want to set/unset DNS

I've tested this code on the latest version of Windows 10 and it works like a charm!

Here is the code to find the active Ethernet or Wifi network (Not 100% accurate but useful in most cases)

```
public static NetworkInterface GetActiveEthernetOrWifiNetworkInterface()
{
    var Nic = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(
        a => a.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up &&
        (a.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 || a.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet) &&
        a.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Any(g => g.Address.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork"));

    return Nic;
}
```

**SetDNS**

```
public static void SetDNS(string DnsString)
{
    string[] Dns = { DnsString };
    var CurrentInterface = GetActiveEthernetOrWifiNetworkInterface();
    if (CurrentInterface == null) return;

    ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();
    foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
    {
        if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
        {
            if (objMO["Description"].ToString().Equals(CurrentInterface.Description))
            {
                ManagementBaseObject objdns = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
                if (objdns != null)
                {
                    objdns["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = Dns;
                    objMO.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", objdns, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UnsetDNS**

```
public static void UnsetDNS()
{
    var CurrentInterface = GetActiveEthernetOrWifiNetworkInterface();
        if (CurrentInterface == null) return;

    ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();
    foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
    {
        if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
        {
            if (objMO["Description"].ToString().Equals(CurrentInterface.Description))
            {
                ManagementBaseObject objdns = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
                if (objdns != null)
                {
                    objdns["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = null;
                    objMO.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", objdns, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
SetDNS("127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: I feel this could accidentally set DNS on multiple NICs should the PC have 2 NICs with the same description which I believe is possible. It is usually better to use WMI to get the exact NIC name and then use `["Caption"].Equals` to make sure you have the device you want.

Comment: You must run as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Combining multiple solutions I found that the following code is working great for Windows 10 and 8.1 (others not tested, but should work as well):

```
public static void setDNS(string NIC, string DNS)
{
    ConnectionOptions options = PrepareOptions();
    ManagementScope scope = PrepareScope(Environment.MachineName, options, @"\root\CIMV2");
    ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
    ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(scope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);
    ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        if ((bool)mo["IPEnabled"])
        {
            if (mo["Caption"].ToString().Contains(NIC))
            {
                try
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject newDNS = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
                    newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = DNS.Split(',');
                    ManagementBaseObject setDNS = mo.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDNS, null);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The application needs to run with elevated permissions (in my case I'm starting an elevated process running an .exe):

```
private void callSwapDNS(string NIC, string DNS)
{
    const int ERROR_CANCELLED = 1223; //The operation was canceled by the user.
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"swap.exe");
    string wrapped = string.Format(@"""{0}"" ""{1}""", NIC, DNS);
    info.Arguments = wrapped;
    info.UseShellExecute = true;
    info.Verb = "runas";
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    try
    {
        Process.Start(info);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    catch (Win32Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.NativeErrorCode == ERROR_CANCELLED)
            MessageBox.Show("Why you no select Yes?");
        else
            throw;
    }
}
```

Using `mo["Caption"].ToString().Contains(NIC)` doesn't work for Windows 10 as the WMI query returns the NIC-Name leading with [000000]

> [000000] Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection

on my Windows 10 machine.

Credit to the following answers: [WMI not working after upgrading to Windows 10

[WMI not working after upgrading to Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034688/wmi-not-working-after-upgrading-to-windows-10)
[How can you change Network settings (IP Address, DNS, WINS, Host Name) with code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and the answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows 10 you may need authentication first. Pass a ConnectionOptions instance to a ManagementScope constructor, defining your Authentication and Impersonation properties.

Try this:

```
// Method to prepare the WMI query connection options.
public static ConnectionOptions PrepareOptions ( )
{
  ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions ( );
  options . Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel . Impersonate;
  options . Authentication = AuthenticationLevel . Default;
  options . EnablePrivileges = true;
  return options;
}

// Method to prepare WMI query management scope.
public static ManagementScope PrepareScope ( string machineName , ConnectionOptions options , string path  )
{
  ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope ( );
  scope . Path = new ManagementPath ( @"\\" + machineName + path );
  scope . Options = options;
  scope . Connect ( );
  return scope;
}

// Set DNS.
ConnectionOptions options = PrepareOptions ( );
ManagementScope scope = PrepareScope ( Environment . MachineName , options , @"\root\CIMV2" );
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(scope, "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
    if ((bool)mo["IPEnabled"])
    {
        ManagementBaseObject objdns = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
        if (objdns != null)
        {
            string[] s = { "192.168.XX.X", "XXX.XX.X.XX" };
            objdns["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = s;
            mo.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", objdns, null);
```

Based on this answer:

[WMI not working after upgrading to Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034688/wmi-not-working-after-upgrading-to-windows-10)

Comment: Unfortunately your code has errors: The two arguments for ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(scope, "Wie32[..]") are both marked invalid. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to do this and it works:

```
/// <summary>
/// Set's the DNS Server of the local machine
/// </summary>
/// <param name="NIC">NIC address</param>
/// <param name="DNS">DNS server address</param>
/// <remarks>Requires a reference to the System.Management namespace</remarks>
public void setDNS(string NIC, string DNS)
{
    ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

    foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
    {
        if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
        {
            // if you are using the System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface you'll need to change this line to if (objMO["Caption"].ToString().Contains(NIC)) and pass in the Description property instead of the name 
            if (objMO["Caption"].Equals(NIC))
            {
                try
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject newDNS =
                        objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
                    newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = DNS.Split(',');
                    ManagementBaseObject setDNS =
                        objMO.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDNS, null);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I think it originally came from here
: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code

Comment: That's the same code I'm using as well but it doesn't work anymore with Windows 10.

Comment: are you only changing `if (objMO["Caption"].Equals(NIC))`?

Comment: are you running elevated / with admin privileges?

Comment: Try to disable your firewall and see if the change takes effect then... I seem to remember there were problems with BitDefender and Avast Firewall... Sorry I can't be more specific as i just can't remember the details :)