# How to set prefered and alternate DNS Server using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dns, static

How can I set the preferred and alternate DNS Server using VB.NET?

[image: stting ip]

I managed to set static the IP, subnet and gateway, using below method:

```
For Each objMO As ManagementObject In objMOC
            If (Not CBool(objMO("IPEnabled"))) Then
                Continue For
            End If

            Try
                Dim objNewIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
                Dim objSetIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
                Dim objNewGate As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing


                objNewIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic")
                objNewGate = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways")


                'Set DefaultGateway
                objNewGate("DefaultIPGateway") = New String() {setGateway}

                objNewGate("GatewayCostMetric") = New Integer() {1}

                'Set IPAddress and Subnet Mask
                objNewIP("IPAddress") = New String() {setIPAddress}
                objNewIP("SubnetMask") = New String() {setSubnetMask}

                objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", objNewIP, Nothing)
                objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", objNewGate, Nothing)


            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Unable To Set IP : " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next objMO
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40291375/8967612) might help. It's for C# but should be easy enough to translate.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, thank you.. it works!